# Check if JavaScript function returns without executing it?

Tags: javascript, function, return, conditional-statements

I have a given function that takes, among other arguments, two optional arguments which may be functions. Both need to be optional, one will be a function, and one will either be a boolean or a function that returns a boolean.

```
// Obj.func(variable, String[, Object][, Boolean||Function][, Function]);
Obj.func = function(other, assorted, args, BoolOrFunc, SecondFunc) {
    // execution
};

Obj.func(
    [
        'some',
         'data'
    ],
    'of varying types',
    {
        and: 'some optional arguments'
    },
    function() {
        if(some condition) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
    function() {
       // do things without returning
    }
);
```

It is my desire that both functions (and several of the other arguments, if it matters) be optional, which means I have code in the function to determine which arguments the user intended to use.

Unfortunately, as both may be functions, and may be specified directly in the function call, I cannot simply use `typeof` or `instanceof` conditionals. However, since the first function, if it exists, will *always* return a boolean (and the second function will not return at all), one idea I had would be to check its return value:

```
if(typeof BoolOrFunc === 'boolean'
   || (typeof BoolOrFunc === 'function' && typeof BoolOrFunc() === 'boolean')) {
    // BoolOrFunc is either a boolean or a function that returns a boolean.
    // Handle it as the intended argument.
} else {
    // Otherwise, assume value passed as BoolOrFunc is actually SecondFunc,
    // and BoolOrFunc is undefined.
}
```

This works in principle; however, running `typeof BoolOrFunc()` executes the function, which causes a problem if the function does more than just return a boolean: that is, if the function passed as `BoolOrFunc` is *actually* meant to be `SecondFunc`. `SecondFunc`, in this case, is something of a callback function, and may perform actions, including DOM modifications, that I don't want to execute immediately.

For this reason, my question is: **Is there a way to check if a function returns without executing it?**

One thing I had considered was to call `BoolOrFunc.toString()`, then perform a Regular Expression search for the return value, something along the lines of…

```
if(typeof BoolOrFunc === 'boolean'
   || (typeof BoolOrFunc === 'function'
       && BoolOrFunc.toString().search(/return (true|false);/) !== -1)) {
    // BoolOrFunc is either a boolean or contains a return string with a boolean.
    // Handle it as the intended argument.
}
```

Note that the above code may not work as written: I've not actually built a test case for it, because, well, it seems exceptionally inefficient and potentially unreliable, and I figured someone here might have a more elegant solution to my quandary. That having been said, I figured I'd include it for discussion purposes.

Comment: As an anecdotal side note, this is pretty close to the Halting Problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) which is undecidable over Turing Machines. :)

Comment: Heh, you bring up a good point. I'm probably expecting far too much from JS. :P

Comment: For the case that users call the form which giving a boolean and a function that returns a boolean, can you require instead that they pass in the arguments wrapped in an object e.g. `Obj.func(myvar, mystring, myobj, {boolarg: true, funcarg: my_func_that_returns_bool});` or something like that, to make it unambiguous what it is. Then the user must ensure that `my_func_that_returns_bool` does as it claims

Answer (score 1):

Meshaal made a prediction in the question:

```
"... one will either be a boolean or a function that returns a boolean."
"... first function, if it exists, will always return a boolean."
```

With this prediction the function is not a Turing Machine, because we know that it returns something. Surely it can't be done with a simple RegExp: just `return !0` would break the example.

But if you **parse** the result of function.toString() with a parser being intelligent enough to find all possible return points, the problem should principally be solvable.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, if I understand correctly.  First, I'd probably warn against having such open-ended arguments.  I'm curious as to the use case.

But that said, it's easy enough to get around the problems you mention (which may not wholly solve your problem).

> This works in principle; however, running typeof BoolOrFunc() executes the function...

That's easy enough to fix, I think.  At first, just check to see if `BoolOrFunc` is a boolean or a function (just `typeof BoolOrFunc`, natch).  If it's a boolean, I assume we're fine.  Either `SecondFunc` is missing (`undefined`) or a `function` -- or we're in an error state.  That's all easy to handle in this first case.

So let's assume the second case, that we have `BoolOrFunc-As-Function`.  We're going to have to execute it, whether it's "really" `BoolOrFunc` *or* `SecondFunc`, so, at the last moment possible in your code, do so.

This is obviously where things get complicated without more pseudo-code (or production code) from you.  If the "possible `BoolOrFunc`" returns `true` or `false`, you know you have a function version of `BoolOrFunc`.  If it returns `undefined`, you know you just called `SecondFunc`.  Again, depending on what you're trying to do, you branch here.  If you have a `true` or `false`, you have to process out "BoolOrFunc-as-function", else you've called `SecondFunc` and are likely done.

That doesn't answer the more generic question of how to tell if a function returns a specific type without calling it, but does solve your use case as presented here.

But this specific more generic case [sic] isn't too difficult, as long as we're dealing with **real, constant booleans** in the `return`s.  In that case, the regexp route would work -- find all `return\s+.*;` and make sure what follows each `return` is `true` or `false`.  Or just compare total `return` count is the same as that for `return\s+(false|true);`.  Or something.  And hope the javascript in the function is well formed.  What a bear already.

If the function can return local variables (`return MightBeBoolean;` rather than `return true;`), you're nearly toast -- or if you accept truthiness or falsiness, you're nearly toast again, since `undefined` is falsey, and you can't tell the difference between `BoolOrFunc` or `SecondFunc` (which would always return "falsey").  It's possible, but not nearly worth writing the parser in any reasonable use case I can imagine.  And if you're importing a lib to do that, sheesh.  Good luck.  Seems like overkill to have function that's slightly more defensive in its calling.

I do wonder if either functions passed as arguments are themselves passed arguments from your `Obj.func`, which would make things even more interesting.

Got more real code?  ;^)  But ultimately I'm recommending you don't do the "pass any jumble of arguments, as long as they're in order".  I think you can likely do the BoolOrFunc/SecondFunc late evaluation.  Otherwise, I hate to say it, but code a bit more *of*fensively here.